# Error when using assert() and convert c-string to std::string on mac

Tags: c++, c++11

I was provided this piece of code to test my library and I save it in a file called main.cc

```
ostringstream oss; 
oss.str("");
serialize(0x123456789abcdef0L, oss);
assert(oss.str() == "l\x80\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf0"s);
```

The s at the end is to convert c-string to std::string. However, when I run my makefile, the compiler gives me these error

fatal error: expected ')'

```
assert(oss.str() == "l\x80\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf0"s); 
                                                           ^
```

main.cc:21:5: note: to match this '('

```
assert(oss.str() == "l\x80\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf0"s);   
^
```

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:93:24: note: 
      expanded from macro 'assert'
    (**builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func**, **FILE**, __LINE...

I don't know how to handle this case. Can someone explain and help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Add `using namespace std::string_literals;` But in actual fact you don't really need the trailing `s`

Comment: Okay..so `s` is a string literal.

Comment: @GauravSehgal I think it's a string literal operator.

Comment: @john is correct, but please ensure you are compiling with c++14 (your question is tagged with c++11)

Comment: @vasek Sadly the course I am taking is using c++11, so I'm trying to find a way that works with c11

Comment: @john But my instructor wants us to use it

Comment: @vnsoshi The `s` string literal operator was introduced in C++14, so you've been given an impossible task. Go back to your instructor.